# Wildfly 17 + Json-b

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly, wildfly-17

I am attempting to use the Json-B API that is part of the Java EE 8 specification within Wildfly 17.  Wildfly 17 is a certified Java EE 8 implementation, however the Json-B API classes are not found on the servers classpath when I attempt to use `Jsonb` or `JsonBuilder`.  Eclipse has the Wildfly 17 Runtime included as part of my project however I still receive a message stating the type cannot be resolved: `Jsonb cannot be resolved to a type`?

Can someone confirm if Json-B is included in Wildfly 17.0?

Answer (score 0):

JSON-B is definitely included in WildFly and [added](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/17.0.1.Final/ee/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/ee/subsystem/EeSubsystemRootResource.java#L118-L119) as a dependency to each deployment.

I'm not all that familiar with adding dependencies to Eclipse, however you'd definitely need to add it there as well for the IDE to recognize it.

Comment: Using a Wildfly 17.0.0.1 and the latest version of the JBoss tools the Jsonb class fails to import in eclipse.